# Web-ContextPath doesn't seem to be working in Liferay

Tags: java, liferay, osgi, liferay-7, bnd

I am building a simple Single Page Application with JAX-RS backend bundled into Liferay 7. I want app's static files to be served from the same bundle, so I created `META-INF/resources` folder and put all the files there. Next, I added `Web-ContextPath: /demo-spa-react` to bnd.bnd file, but when I try to access /o/demo-spa-react/index.html, I get 404 error. Am I missing something? I tried to force dependency on javax.servlet on bnd.bnd just in case, but that had no effect either.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: First, make sure your bundle is active (use gogo shell to check). In case there are missing dependencies, no need to go hunting higher up the stack

Comment: @OlafKock Yeah, I checked it. The bundle also contains JAX-RS service, which works just fine. The issue is precisely with serving static resources.

Comment: did you found any resolution to this ? @foverzar